# Is it possible to connect tableau to cloudera hive in windows 7?

Tags: windows, hive, cloudera, tableau-api

I downloaded and installed cloudera hive drivers provided in the link http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/drivers. But when I try to add driver in ODBC connections, it is not shown there. I read some where that cloudera hive driver will work only
with windows 2008. I am using windows 7. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2):

A little late in the day, but here are some more detailed articles from the Tableau Knowledge Base may be of interest to you or anyone else interested in this question.

[Connecting to Hadoop Hive](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/cloudera-hadoop-hive-connection)

[Extra Capabilities for Hadoop Hive](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/cloudera-hadoop-hive-extra-capabilities)

[Designing for Performance Using Hadoop Hive](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/cloudera-hadoop-hive-performance)

[Administering Hadoop and Hive for Tableau Connectivity](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/administering-hadoop-hive)

Failing that, if you are still unable to connect to Cloudera Hive and you're a registered customer, or have downloaded a trial, then you can always drop an email to support@tableausoftware.com and ask for help there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to connect Tableau to cloudera Hive on Windows 7.

Steps are:
1. start the thrift server for hive
 nohup HIVE_PORT=10000 hive --service hiveserver & 
2. install the Hive ODBC driver from  https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/con/Cloudera+Connector+for+Tableau+License+Agreement 
3. open Tableau
 Connect to Data -> Cloudera Hadoop Hive -> Give the server ip and port :10000 (you can change the thrift server port if you need to by changing HIVE_PORT to some other value while starting the Hive server)

The rest is straight forward.
Also make sure that the required port (10000 or which ever you chose) is open in the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you tried to create the ODBC connection in ODBC 32bit, since the drivers and the Tableau desktop is a 32bit application. You can run the ODBC 32bit driver panel with the odbcad32.exe command line.